# Guitar buzzing after replacing bridge pickup

Tags: guitar, wiring, buzz

I replaced my humbucker bridge pickup with a different one (humbucker as well) and now I have this buzzing when I'm not touching any metal part on my guitar (string or pots). I wired the pup exactly as the previous one was and did not touch anything else.

I checked with a multimeter and all seems to be grounded well (including the bridge ground cable) and nothing seems to be shorted. Once I touch a metal part the buzz stops completely.

Any suggestions? This is very frustrating!

Answer (score 3):

I found this very helpful link: http://www.guitarnuts.com/wiring/shielding/shield3.php and I found out I had ground loops; removing them improved the issue a lot. There is much more shielding stuff to do in this link, requiring more material and time, so I definitely recommend it.