# Do I have a grounding issue?

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups, repair, wiring

I am asking a question regarding my PRS SE7. It has 2 humbucking pickups and recently, I have noticed a substantial amount of noise in my signal. The noise diminishes when I touch the strings or any metal but is still apparent. My jack kept coming loose and I would have to tighten it every couple of days and then I finally had to lock it down hard lol. Another note to add is that it is coil tapped and the noise is much less obvious in certain selections. The last thing to add is that the noise is gone when I cut back the volume completely or the tone control. I have tried several cables and all the results are the same. I just wanted to make sure this is the guitar and nothing else. What does this sound like to you?

Comment: Have a look at http://music.stackexchange.com/q/8197/104

Answer (score 6):

Often when a jack socket comes loose, the owner keeps tightening it from outside. This makes the wire attached to the part of the socket which is either inside the guitar body, or under the scratchplate, to turn round. It will only go so far before it either breaks or shorts or touches another component. Sounds like you need to get at the inside part of that socket, and sort it out from there. When re-tightening, stop the side with the wires attached from turning as the nut is tightened.

Comment: i beat the crap out of my guitars.  (punk bands) a bit of blue locktite on the jack socket helps prevent it from coming loose again.